# Constraint Fk Composta

Tags: sql, oracle

Ola,

Estou criando uma constraint de foreign key composta assim:

```
alter table "Tabela1" add constraint constraint_fk foreign key ("Guid","Tabela2Id") references "Tabela2" ("Guid","Tabela2Id")
```

Quando eu do o refresh na tabela, aparece assim:

```
constraint contraint_fk foreign key ("Tabela2Id","Guid") references "Tabela2" ("Tabela2Id","Guid")
```

Esta invertido os ids (Guid e Tabela2Id)....

Quando faço o **insert** pelo **backend**, eu recebo um **erro**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Publica a estrutura das tabelas

Comment: Encontrei o erro, na tabela2, a PK esta ("Tabela2Id","Guid"). Portanto, quando criava a fk, automaticamente ele invertia...